# Unable to connect to my oracle XE database

Tags: database, oracle, informatica

I am unable to connect to my oracle XE database through sql dveloper after changing my system host name. Please help me to connect to database.

Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:

```
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
```

Comment: Check your tnsnames file. Do you have an entry for localhost or specific to the previous host name?

Comment: yes, i changed it to new host name in tnsnames and listner ora file,,,,,still i am facing the same issue

Comment: Did you check your /etc/hosts and/or your sqlnet.ora files to ensure they didn't retain any of the old host specifications?

Comment: if your listener is listening on localhost/127.0.0.1 just connect via that - assuming your setup is a single machine

Comment: yes,i added ip address and hostname  in hosts file and found SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS) in sqlnet.ora ...still its not connecting